# Is there a public API server for Stellar?

Tags: stellar

I'm writing a Stellar application. I'm looking to use the API provided by stellard without running a copy of it myself.

Is there a public API server for Stellar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep:

https://www.stellar.org/api/

> Stellar Foundation runs two instances of stellard you can use if you
> don't want to run your own.
>
> network   address           RPC Port  Websocket Port
> test          test.stellar.org 9002          9001
> live           live.stellar.org 9002          9001

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try the new API look at this page: https://www.stellar.org/galaxy/getting-started/